# How to enable scientific mode in Pycharm Remote Gateway?

Tags: pycharm

I am using Pycharm to work on a remote project and would like to turn on the scientific mode. Unfortunately, I couldn't find it under the View tab. Is there any way I can turn it on?

Also it seems I can't run block of code or selected code while working on a remote project. Is there a solution on this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is it PyCharm Professional?

Scientific Mode is a Professional-only feature.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/matplotlib-support.html